# External HD suddenly stopped working

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have (or had) a Samsung M3 1TB drive.

Yesterday I removed it and it was working normally, today, I plugged it in, and the LED turns on normally, but the "engine" of the HD not. So, the HD is not recognized (because it seems to be off).

Any chance I can workaround this somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be lucky and it's just the USB enclosure that has failed. Try opening it and checking the contacts.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't master the electronic sciences.. I don't even know how to open it (there is no screws)... any protip about this?

Comment: It probably slides out. Search google for [open Samsung M3](https://www.google.com/search?q=open+Samsung+M3).

Answer (score 1):

The M3 enclosure is hard to prise open. Use a very thin and wide metal spatula to initially create a gap then use a spudger to prise open the catches. They are situated 2 either end and 3 each side. The drive itself has a proprietary USB3 board (not SATA) attached so there is very little you can alter once open as the USB3 cable connects directly to the drive.

Answer (score 0):

I had an IOMEGA drive with a similar issue and I recovered my data by opening the USB enclosure, removing the drive and connecting it directly to my desktop. I could then copy the files over to another drive normally.

External drives are usually just normal desktop HDDs with a USB enclosure. If the LED lights up but the drive does not start spinning, it could be as simple as the internal power cable being unplugged. Just open it and have a look, it is often very obvious:

[image]

You should see something like the image above, make sure both cables are well connected. Your issue might be a deeper problem of course but this is a good first step to check.